# How can I track a git repository in a different directory?

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules

So I have a project that is a git repo which contains another git repository. So the structure is this:

```
/gitProject
    /other
    /stuff
    /anotherGitProject
```

Currently, I've got anotherGitProject set up as a submodule of gitProject. My problem is that I have to deploy anotherGitProject to another part of my hard drive. Since anotherGitProject functions as an add-on, I just copy the contents of anotherGitProject directly into the other project's directory tree:

```
/gitProject
    /other
    /stuff
    /anotherGitProject
/otherProject
    /(contents of anotherGitProject+otherProject)
```

My question is: How can I keep track of the changes I make to anotherGitProject within gitProject? This seems really convoluted, but I need to make changes to anotherGitProject on top of otherProject or else this wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to:

- clone `anotherGitProject` in `otherProject`,
  or even *as* otherProject (if the content of `anotherGitProject` needs to be directly within  `otherProject`, in which case:

  - rename  `otherProject` in  `otherProject.tmp`
  - clone  `anotherGitProject` as `otherProject`
  - copy the rest of  `otherProject.tmp` content in  `otherProject`
  - add a .gitignore to ignore anything which isn't `anotherGitProject` original content
- add to `anotherGitProject` initial repo (the one being a submodule to `gitProject`) a [**remote**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) pointing to `otherProject`

That way, you can fetch/pull from `otherProject`directly back in `anotherGitProject`

If  `anotherGitProject` is, as a plugin, a simple subdirectory of  `otherProject`, the process is much simpler, since, as I mention in my first point, you can simply clone  `anotherGitProject` directly in the destination (within `otherProject`).
The remote step is the same:

```
cd /gitProject/anotherGitProject
git add remote anotherGitProjectDeployed /path/to/otherProject/anotherGitProject
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The key thing for me was creating a remote for anotherGitProject. Since I didn't own it, I had to create my own version of it on github, and then used that as a submodule within gitProject.